# How to access views outside of oncreateView() in fragment

Tags: java, android

In fragment, I have a progress bar. I want to hide that progress bar in outside of oncreateView() method. I tried some code but its not hide

Please anyone fix.

Here my code:

```js
public class ChangeMobileOtp extends Fragment {

    static TextView mobcode;
    Button verify;
    ProgressBar prgSpin;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_mobile_code, container,
                false);

        mobcode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_verificationtxt);
        verify = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.mverify_button);
        prgSpin = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.mobSpin);
        prgSpin.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

        return view;

    }


    public void recivedSms(String message)
    {
        try
        {

            mobcode.setText(message);
            Log.d("otps", message);
            prgSpin.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide progress bar

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Another javaClass

```js
public class IncomingOtp extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj .length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])                                                                                                    pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber ;
                    String message = currentMessage .getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String otp = message.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    try
                    {
                        if (senderNum.contains("RIDSHR"))
                        {
                            ChangeMobileOtp Sms = new ChangeMobileOtp();
                            Sms.recivedSms(otp.trim().substring(1));
                            Log.d("Otp",otp.trim().substring(1));
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Please anyone help to fix that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Log.d("otps", message); is successfully printed ?

Comment: Where are you calling recivedSms("") ?

Comment: Where calling `recivedSms ` method?

Comment: i called recivedSms method in another java class

Comment: Make progress bar static and call it using class name in another class to hide it

Comment: i didn't understand, see my updated code and then tell how to do

Answer (score 0):

First of create a functionality class for progressbar similar to the below one:

ProgressUtil.java:

```
public class ProgressUtil {


public static void showProgressDialog(ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

public static void hideProgressDialog(ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Now in your fragment create a progressDialog variable in the class:

```
 ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Initialise in the onCreateView() method:

```
 progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

now whereever you want to show or hide the progressbar, use below commands based on your requirement:

```
 ProgressUtil.hideProgressDialog(progressDialog);//Hiding
 ProgressUtil.showProgressDialog(progressDialog);//showing
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @appu-Just replace the progressbar variable in place of a ProgressDialog and make changes based on codes for a progressbar